# Wiring an outlet from a light switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, receptacle

I've just moved into a new place which has an outhouse. In there, there is an overhead fluorescent light (and two more under the floorboards for some reason) as well as two 2-socket outlets. The lights are all powered but none of the sockets is (the wires have been messily cut with bare cable-ends coming out of the outlets.) 
I'd like to get power to at least one socket, for a single 200watt heating lamp running via an electronic thermostat. Will that be something I with no electrical experience could do? Or would it be a simple job for an electrician? I'd rather not get into raising floorboards (where the existing wiring, both connected and cut-off runs) if possible and I don't mind losing power to all of the lights.

Any advice? Cheers!

Comment: "Is this something someone with no electrical literacy can do?" No.  "Is it possible to gain electrical literacy?" Yes. "How?" Something that provides a well-rounded *primer* touching on all aspects, classically a book on home electrical from the library.  Google isn't any help until you have the primer, it only answers questions, and you first need to know which questions to ask.

Comment: okay my bad, I didn't realise this site was not for people to ask for advice from more experienced people, let me just go down to the library and look it up instead. I don't even know what point you're trying to make because you're trying so hard to act superior.

Comment: Sorry if I lent that impression.  Your situation is mildly complex and you've provided far too little detail to be answerable. Since you profess to have no electrical experience, I presume you are not telling us more because you don't have the lexicon to describe it.  Fair enough. I am advising you where to get that lexicon most efficiently, assuming you are an intelligent person who both recognizes the limits of your knowledge and seeks to expand it.  I could be wrong but I like to assume the best of people.

Comment: Also this may be my blindside here, but I assume your goal here is to get the project all the way to the finish line yourself with self-obtained skills.  Rereading your questions closer, I now see where you are not asking for a wire-by-wire instructable, but more of a scoping question.   I simply thought "why hire work out you are not far off from being able to do yourself, how about we just get you there".

Comment: ... fluorescent lights under the floorboards of an outhouse? To light the, uh, deposits?